# Angular 2+ How to validate maximum allowed value on input using ngmodel

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am stuck on a rather simple issue it seems. I have an input that I want to display an error if the entered value exceeds 9999.99

My current code looks like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
              <input matInput ngModel #checkAmount="ngModel" placeholder="Check Amount" name="checkAmount" required pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?">
              <mat-error *ngIf="checkAmount.touched && checkAmount.errors?.required">
                Please enter check amount.
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="checkAmount.touched && checkAmount.errors?.pattern">
                Please enter valid check amount.
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
```

I have tried checkAmount.value > 9999.99 but no dice

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What I can see is that your pattern makes sure that input could contain only digits and dot. There wasn't any comparison.

Comment: @QuanVO that is correct, I am not sure how I can actually validate that value does not exceed 9999.99

Comment: You can either change the pattern to `[0-9]{0,4}(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?` to limit the number of digits before the dot to 4 or convert `checkAmount` to a number and compare it in `ngIf`.

Comment: @QuanVO thank you, this is what I was looking for, what is the correct way to compare it in ngIf ?

Comment: As I checked, `mat-error` only shows when there is a form validation error even if you set `ngIf` to true, so the best way, in my opinion, is defining a custom [validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).